# syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file

Tags: php

quiero mostrar categorias relacionadas en entradas pero me sale este error y he probado con codigos similares y pasa lo mismo, me podrian ayudar.

```
<?php
function dc_related_after_content( $content ) 
{ 
if ( !is_singular('post') ) return $content;    
$cad            = "";
$template_li    = '<li>
                        <a class="thumb_rel" href="{url}">{thumb}</a>
                        <a class="title_rel" href="{url}">{title}</a>
                    </li>';
$template_rel   = '<div class="rel_posts">
                        <h3>Artículos Relacionados</h3>
                        <ul>
                            {list}
                        </ul>
                   </div>';
    if ( $cad ) 
    {
        $content .= str_replace('{list}', $cad, $template_rel);
    }
}
  wp_reset_query();
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'dc_related_after_content');
```

Comment: @Benito-B, acabo de probar en PHP 7.2 y no hay problema con los saltos de línea.

Comment: @Triby PHP sólo empeora...

Comment: @Alfabravo, no es de ahora, es una característica que tiene muchos años, encontré publicaciones del 2010 que hablan de esto. Por otra parte, el origen de PHP fue como un sistema de plantillas para facilitar la creación de contenidos y manejo de formularios; varios años después comenzó la transformación. Tiene sus cosas muy malas, pero también tiene otras muy buenas y, por supuesto, mucho camino por recorrer.

Answer (score -1):

La llave está cerrando la función y 2 líneas más abajo estás retornando `$content` que es del parámetro de la función

```
<?php
function dc_related_after_content( $content ) 
{ 
if ( !is_singular('post') ) return $content;    
$cad            = "";
$template_li    = '<li>
                        <a class="thumb_rel" href="{url}">{thumb}</a>
                        <a class="title_rel" href="{url}">{title}</a>
                    </li>';
$template_rel   = '<div class="rel_posts">
                        <h3>Artículos Relacionados</h3>
                        <ul>
                            {list}
                        </ul>
                   </div>';
    if ( $cad ) 
    {
        $content .= str_replace('{list}', $cad, $template_rel);
    }
}//<- He aquí el problema
  wp_reset_query();
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'dc_related_after_content');
```

Comment: Recuerda que salvo que sea absolutamente necesario, es mejor evitar usar imágenes para responder, por ejemplo aquí pudiste incluir un comentario en la zona donde esta el problema

Comment: Vas a poner al pobre ser a trabajar con una imagen? El código, en preguntas y respuestas, va como texto.

Comment: Ok ok, haré el cambio